# JBoss AS 6 Logging Patterns

Tags: logging, jboss, log4j

In the deployment directory of JBoss 6, there is `jboss-logging.xml`:

The `FILE` appender has following pattern:

```
<pattern-formatter pattern="%d %-5p [%c] (%t:%x) %s%E%n"/>
```

This outputs something as follows:

```
2010-08-02 17:41:43,845 INFO  [STDOUT] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-1:)   2010-08-02 17:41:43,844  INFO [http-127.0.0.1-8080-1] (XyzPageController.java:<init>:58) - New abc instantiated and empty xyz constructed.
```

I'm wondering what the **%s%E** tokens stand for...
Is this something JBoss 6 specific?

Answer (score 7):

from http://i0.grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.jboss.logmanager/jboss-logmanager/1.2.0.GA/org/jboss/logmanager/formatters/FormatStringParser.java

The %E is the stack trace and %s is the message.

Answer (score 2):

The whole `jboss-logging.xml` file is JBoss-specific - from JBossAS 6, they're using a proprietary logging configuration, rather than using `jboss-log4j.xml` like they did in previous versions.

I can't find any documentation as to what it means, though. This stuff is still in beta, so the docs may not exist yet.

Comment: Just posted a question @ the JBoss Forum: http://community.jboss.org/message/556245

Comment: It's a pain ! It's the whole story of open source, a big bazar; Hey guys from jboss it's time to clean you rooms ! It's not serious neither professional...

Answer (score 2):

Refer this manual.
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6/html/Administration_and_Configuration_Guide/chap-The_Logging_Subsystem.html#Log_Formatter_Syntax1

`%s`    The simple log message (no exception trace)

`%E`    The exception stack trace (with extended module information)

Answer (score 0):

I want to share mine, my goal was to "copy" the Eclipse's one. 
There is no documentation, and it differs a little bit from Apache's pattern. Hope it helps.

```
        <formatter name="ECLIPSE_PATTERN">
               <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
        </formatter>
```

Really I use the following (to get the class and the method)

```
        <formatter name="ECLIPSE_PATTERN_WITH_METHOD">
            <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %-120s%E {%l}%n"/>
        </formatter>
```